# Bresenham algorithm in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, bresenham

I need a fast algorithm for calculating coordinates for a line between two points. I tried to find good JavaScript Bresenham implementation, but there are too many and quite confusing publications. In wikipedia - [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm) the fastest and most simple form (no divisions and error calculation for both directions) is presented in pseudocode like this:

```
 function line(x0, y0, x1, y1)
   dx := abs(x1-x0)
   dy := abs(y1-y0) 
   if x0 < x1 then sx := 1 else sx := -1
   if y0 < y1 then sy := 1 else sy := -1
   err := dx-dy

   loop
     setPixel(x0,y0)
     if x0 = x1 and y0 = y1 exit loop
     e2 := 2*err
     if e2 > -dy then 
       err := err - dy
       x0 := x0 + sx 
     if e2 <  dx then 
       err := err + dx
       y0 := y0 + sy 
   end loop
```

Do you know of a simple and robust JavaScript Bresenham implementation based on this pseudocode?

Comment: I was looking for the same exact thing, and recently stumbled on this interactive implementation of the [bresenham's line algorithm in javascript](https://web.archive.org/web/20191104140129/http://www.javascriptteacher.com/bresenham-line-drawing-algorithm.html) -- move mouse around to also move the line. Kind of neat to see it in action, rather than just algorithm source code. Neat explanation too.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Rewriting your supplied pseudo-code into JavaScript:

```js
const { abs, sign } = Math;

function line(x0, y0, x1, y1) {
  const dx = abs(x1 - x0);
  const dy = abs(y1 - y0);
  const sx = sign(x1 - x0);
  const sy = sign(y1 - y0);
  let err = dx - dy;

  while (true) {
    setPixel(x0, y0); // Do what you need to for this

    if (x0 === x1 && y0 === y1) break;

    const e2 = 2 * err;
    if (e2 > -dy) { err -= dy; x0 += sx; }
    if (e2 <  dx) { err += dx; y0 += sy; }
  }
}
```

Note that comparing floats directly may fail as you step (though it shouldn't when stepping by integer amounts, it might if either end point is non-integer), so instead of directly comparing the end points you might want to use an epsilon:

```js
const { abs, sign } = Math;
const epsilon = 0.0001;

function line(x0, y0, x1, y1) {
  ...
  while (true) {
    ...
    if (abs(x0 - x1) + abs(y0 - y1) < epsilon) break;
    ...
  }
}
```

This will necessarily slow you down, however, so only do this if you are dealing with non-integers.

Comment: Brasenham is only supposed to work on integers anyways. It is used to calculate which pixels to color to draw a line.

Comment: I like this one, but I think it can be further improved by removing the break in favor of real loop condition and doing the multiplication by two with shift.

Comment: The bit shift might be a hair faster, but I doubt that changing the loop would affect performance. You could easily change it to `while(x0!=x1 || y0!=y1)` and remove the `if/break`, but you would need to pull out another call to `setPixel` before/after the loop to handle the end point of the line correctly and the edge case.

Comment: Quite right, I also noticed that about the edge conditions. Thanks!

Comment: Also note that bit shifting in JS forces integers down from 53 bits to 32 bits, so unless you know your domain won't exceed 32 bit it's usually better not to use that shortcut.

Answer (score 8):

<sub>**Disclaimer**: I extracted this answer from the OPs question. [Answers should not be contained in the question itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309555/316262).</sub>

---

#### Answer provided by [Boris Hamanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/427205/boris-hamanov):

Thanks everybody! This is what I came with at the end:

```
function calcStraightLine (startCoordinates, endCoordinates) {
    var coordinatesArray = new Array();
    // Translate coordinates
    var x1 = startCoordinates.left;
    var y1 = startCoordinates.top;
    var x2 = endCoordinates.left;
    var y2 = endCoordinates.top;
    // Define differences and error check
    var dx = Math.abs(x2 - x1);
    var dy = Math.abs(y2 - y1);
    var sx = (x1 < x2) ? 1 : -1;
    var sy = (y1 < y2) ? 1 : -1;
    var err = dx - dy;
    // Set first coordinates
    coordinatesArray.push(new Coordinates(y1, x1));
    // Main loop
    while (!((x1 == x2) && (y1 == y2))) {
        var e2 = err << 1;
        if (e2 > -dy) {
            err -= dy;
            x1 += sx;
        }
        if (e2 < dx) {
            err += dx;
            y1 += sy;
        }
        // Set coordinates
        coordinatesArray.push(new Coordinates(y1, x1));
    }
    // Return the result
    return coordinatesArray;
}
```