# How to get list of all coordinates between two points?

Tags: android, coordinates

I have modified this answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13491882/884674) Javascript answer.

they were having "null"  which I replaced with zero.

But, it is having many glitches.

```
public ArrayList<Point> getListOfIntermediatePoints(Point A, Point B ){
        float m = slope(A, B);
        int C = (int) intercept(A, m);

        ArrayList<Point> coordinates = new ArrayList<Point>(); 
        for (int i = A.x; i <= B.x; i++) {
            float j = m * i + C; //y = mx + c;
            coordinates.add(new Point(i,(int) j));
        }
        Log.d("coordinates", coordinates+"");
        return coordinates;
    }

    public float slope(Point a, Point b) {
        if (a.x == b.x) {
            return 0;
        }
        return (b.y - a.y) / (b.x - a.x);
    }

    float intercept(Point A, float slope) {
        if (slope == 0) {
            // vertical line
            return A.x;
        }
        return A.y - slope * A.x;
    }
```

Comment: If you could provide what you inputted into the program when it was glitchy, then that would help. Also please explain how it was glitchy so that I can help you to the best of by ability.

Comment: I just tried it and it seems to work perfectly. Just be aware that your B point's x value must be greater than your A point's x value or else it will not work.

Comment: it cannot be perfect. they were using NULL as infinity. but,in this case I cannot use null for int value.