# Bresenham algo makes line too thick

Tags: javascript, math, bresenham

I'm preparing for an interview where I think they could ask me to modify the app I wrote to handle diagonal line drawing.

The simple program can draw a canvas in the terminal and then add shapes to it.

The following `C 20 4` will create:

```
----------------------
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
----------------------
```

Now I'm trying to handle diagonal lines so that `L 2 1 11 4` (that's two points represented as x1, y1, x2, y2) results in:

```
----------------------
| x                  |
|    x               |
|       x            |
|          x         |
----------------------
```

At least that's how I think it should look. I tried both answers from here: [Bresenham algorithm in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672279/bresenham-algorithm-in-javascript)

So the `apply` function looks like this:

```
apply(canvas) {
  const dx = Math.abs(this.x2 - this.x1);
  const dy = Math.abs(this.y2 - this.y1);
  const sx = (this.x1 < this.x2) ? 1 : -1;
  const sy = (this.y1 < this.y2) ? 1 : -1;
  let err = dx - dy;

  let x1 = this.x1;
  let y1 = this.y1;
  let x2 = this.x2;
  let y2 = this.y2;

  canvas.pixels[y1][x1] = 'x';

  while(true) {
    canvas.pixels[y1][x1] = 'x';

    if ((x1 === x2) && (y1 === y2)) break;
    const e2 = 2 * err;
    if (e2 > -dy) { err -= dy; x1 += sx; }
    if (e2 < dx) { err += dx; y1 += sy; }
  }
}
```

But what I'm getting back is too many iterations on the x so the line is too thick:

```
----------------------
| xx                 |
|   xxx              |
|      xxx           |
|         xx         |
----------------------
```

Here is a **runnable demo**: https://repl.it/@DominicTobias/Bresenhams-line-algo

Type `C 20 4`, hit Enter, then `L 2 1 11 4`.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: "that's how I think it should look". What are you basing this on?

Comment: Nothing it’s just want I thought it should look like!

Comment: See [this illustration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm#/media/File:Bresenham.svg) for an example of why Bresenham's works the way it does

Comment: Thanks @Hamms, good to know it's correct